# How to create a Qt Combobox

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, signals-slots, qspinbox

Hi would like to populate a `QCombobox` with a number of items which equals a variable set in a `QSpinBox`

When varying the `QSpinbox` value to N , then the combobox should show the same number of options numbered from 0 to N.

Is it possible to do it with a `QObject::connect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the signal `QSpinBox::valueChanged ( int i )`.

Implement your own class which derives from `QComboBox` and create a slot which has the same signature as the signal.

Something like:

```
public Q_SLOTS:
on_setItemsFromSpinBox( int i );
```

Then you can connect the signal to the slot.

```
connect( m_spinbox,
         SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
         m_my_combobox,
         SLOT(on_setItemsFromSpinBox(int)) );
```

In the slot you clear the combobox (`QComboBox::clear ()`) and then use a loop in which you create as many items as specified by the integer you received in your slot from your signal.